# Convert a Tuple of dictionary to nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have an issue with my code

```
s1 = ({'server_id':'myserver1','cloud':'google','time':'1hr'},
      {'server_id':'myserver2','cloud':'aws','time':'2hr'},
      {'server_id':'myserver3','cloud':'google','time':'1hr'}
      {'server_id':'myserver4','cloud':'aws','time':'3hr'})
mydict = {'mine':
          {data[i]:
           {key:value for key,value in data.iteritems() if key!='cloud'}
          for data in s1 for i in data if i=='cloud'}}
print mydict
```

Result:

```
{'mine': {'aws': {'server_id': 'myserver3','time':'3hr'}}}
```

But I am expecting a result like this

```
{'mine':
 {'aws':
  {'server_id': 'myserver1','time':'1hr'},
  {'server_id': 'myserver3','time':'3hr'}},
 {
 'google':
  {'server_id': 'myserver2','time':'2hr'},
  {'server_id': 'myserver4','time':'4hr'}}}
```

Can any anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider initialising dictionary and appending to it inside a loop. Using `dict.pop` takes care of getting rid of the `cloud` key without having to iterate over the whole thing as you're currently doing so.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)  # {}

for s in s1:
    d[s.pop('cloud')].append(s)  # d.setdefault(s.pop('cloud'), []).append(s)

{'mine' : dict(d)}
```

```
{'mine': {'aws': [{'server_id': 'myserver1', 'time': '1hr'},
   {'server_id': 'myserver2', 'time': '2hr'},
   {'server_id': 'myserver3', 'time': '3hr'}]}}
```

**Disclaimer!** This modifies `s1` in-place (the `pop` mutates the subdict, returning the value for that key if it exists.

To handle KeyErrors, you may provide a suitable default instead - `s.pop('cloud', 'default')` where `default` is the value returned when the `cloud` key does not exist.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I updates the question can you check update the answer

Comment: @Krish I don't get it, my code works for your updated data regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to map three dictionaries to same key. if you make it a list of dictionaries instead, it works.

```
s1 = ({'server_id':'myserver1','cloud':'aws','time':'1hr'},
      {'server_id':'myserver2','cloud':'aws','time':'2hr'},
      {'server_id':'myserver3','cloud':'aws','time':'3hr'})
mydict = {'mine':
          {data['cloud']:
           [{key:value for key, value in data.iteritems() if key != "cloud"}
            for data in s1]}}
print mydict
```

Output:

```
{'mine': {'aws': [{'server_id': 'myserver1', 'time': '1hr'},
   {'server_id': 'myserver2', 'time': '2hr'},
   {'server_id': 'myserver3', 'time': '3hr'}]}}
```

Comment: I updates the question, Can you please check and update the answer

Comment: for such cases, defaultdict is best, as shared by @COLDSPEEF in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944409/4797454